# Using DispatcherServlet for RestController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm currently trying to understand how the Dispatcher Servlet works with the Rest Controller ,but Postman returns 404 on everything I tried thus far.

The rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/applications")
public class ApplicationController {


private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationController.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("ApplDAO")
private ApplDAO applDAO;


@Autowired
ApplicationService objServices;

@RequestMapping(value = "for_user\\{username:\\d+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Application getApp(@PathVariable("username") String username){
    Application app = applDAO.getByUsername(username);
    return app;

  }
}
```

My web.xml

```
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring4-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried using url-pattern /* but with no results.
This is the url I was trying to access http://localhost:8080/project/applications/for_user/username:acid 
Is there something wrong with the URL I'm using or have I used the dispatcher wrong. 
Here is the spring error

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/project/applications/for_user/username:acid

Comment: Why do you use backslashes instead of slashes in your RequestMapping? Why do you use the regex \\d+ if you want to send username:acid (or acid?) as user name. Just use `value = "/for_user/{username}"`, and use `http://localhost:8080/project/applications/for_user/acid`.

Comment: I was watching tutorials and got lost in the huge amount of information ,thanks a lot for clearing it out for me , solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by JB Nizet

> Why do you use backslashes instead of slashes in your RequestMapping?
>   Why do you use the regex \d+ if you want to send username:acid (or
>   acid?) as user name. Just use value = "/for_user/{username}", and use
>   http://localhost:8080/project/applications/for_user/acid.